# cudaThreadSynchronize() failed: Out of memory error when running CRARK to recover RAR password

Tags: passwords

When I run CRARK using CUDA to recover my RAR password I get the following error,

> cudaThreadSynchronize() failed: Out of memory

When I run without `cuda option -c`  it runs fine,
`-d (0-5)`  option does not do any good either.

My System configuration is:

- OSX Lion 10.7.1 (64bit)
- Nvidia 8600 GTM.
- Intel Core 2 duo

Answer (score 0):

From the [cRARk Requirements](http://www.crark.net/cRARk.html#2) page:

> Only NVIDIA cards with computing capability 1.1 and up is supported. (Thus, GeForce 8800 is not)

If an 8800GT is not supported I would not expect an 8600GTM to be supported either.

It is difficult to tell whether any given card supports the full CUDA set, [GPU-z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) is a tool that can tell you, just hover the mouse over the "CUDA" in the bottom row to see the following:

[image]

Otherwise it could simply be that your graphics card (as your error suggests) does not have enough memory.